# What is the competent programmer hypothesis in mutation testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mutation-testing, pitest

While I am learning about mutation testing, I've read in Wikipedia:

> The first is the competent programmer hypothesis. This hypothesis
> states that most software faults introduced by experienced programmers
> are due to small syntactic errors.

I didn't quite understand the competent programmer hypothesis. What do they mean by **syntactic errors**?
I know that syntactic error are caught by the compiler not by mutation testing. How does it relate to mutation testing?

Comment: https://github.com/sttp-book/sttp-book/blob/master/chapters/intelligent-testing/mutation-testing.md

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the source for this quote is dated back to 1978 when the compilers were much less powerful and probably could catch only the dumbest errors :)

In general, I'm not sure there is a general definition for syntactic error applicable to all the (popular) programming languages, partly because some are interpreted not compiled.

So you would probably need to look at the quote in context. Or just don't bother. That Wiki article is quite academic. As long as you understand how mutation testing complements unit testing, you are fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Wiki is wrong. If you read the seminal paper (which wiki references and my PhD advisor wrote), the competent programmer hypothesis is about behavior, not syntax. That is, competent programs behavior is close to being correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).